# issue:A popup(remember password) is coming while login to gmail

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

A popup(remember password) is coming while login to gmail how to pass the control to popup   in selenium webdriver using java,below is the code and throwing exception  ...any suggestions

```
     driver.get("https://www.gmail.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("usrnm");
    driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("pwrd");
    driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS );
    try{
        Alert alert=driver.switchTo().alert();
        System.out.println("alert display");
        alert.dismiss();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("alert didnt display)");
    }
```

Comment: Do you using chrome browser?

Comment: iam using mozilla firefox browser.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "handle"? is it cause to any problem?

Comment: how to click remember me password button or to close popup using selenium

Comment: That seems browser alert , you can try this code  `Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();`

Comment: i have used  it still its not working throwing exception

Comment: what exception it throws?

Comment: Just disable remembering passwords in browser's settings, and the popup won't be displayed anymore. How to disable it depends on concrete browser, for example in Firefox go to menu/security settings/Remember passwords for sites